# MVC4 extendable plug-in architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, architecture

I am trying to create a base MVC4 application that can be extended with plug-ins so future developers of the application won't have to mess with its source code. 
Extensions ranging from (partial)views to data access and api controllers.

The goal is that developers must be able to create a separate plug-in project, build the project and then drop the appropriate files into a plug-in folder, without the need to rebuild the base application.
The plug-in folder is to be stored in the root of the application and would contain a folder for each plugin ie; *web.presentation.statistics.chart1* and *web.api.products.failrate*

I've looked at several subjects like; MEF, OSGi.NET, MVC areas, mvccontrib etc. and many articles and blogs, but they are all either outdated or doesn't fit my requirements.

The way  [nopCommerce plug-ins are written](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/how-to-write-a-nopcommerce-plugin.aspx) is very intriguing, but i must admit the source code is too complicated for a guy like me, new to all plug-in related development.

I hope you can guide me in the right direction and possibly point me towards some technologies or frameworks that could help me. 
Much appreciated.

Comment: Side note: creating reusable architecture is hard. If you want to make an acceptable system make sure to plan for at least 3 distinct system using your architecture to validate and polish all decisions. In your case you would need at very least 3 full scale plugins developed by someone else (in addition to several test/demo versions created by you) before you can claim system works. Getting other people to write code for your unproven project may be a problem - prepare/plan for it in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at Dependency Injection (DI) to allow you to swap implementations of a particular interface. For example, if you have an `IVehicle`, you could have a `Car`, `Truck`, or `Bus` concrete instance injected in. Most DI frameworks will let you configure rules under which different instances are injected.

Regarding API controllers, I've set up inherited Web API controllers. Works great. Here's how I'm doing it...

1. Add a provider that allows `[Route]` attributes to be read from subclasses:

   ```
   public class InheritedAttributeRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
   {
       protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> GetActionRouteFactories(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
       {
           return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>(inherit: true);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set up your `HttpConfiguration` to use this provider:

   ```
   HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new InheritedAttributeRouteProvider());
   ```
3. Create a base controller:

   ```
   public abstract class ControllerBase : ApiController
   {
       [Route]
       public IHttpActionResult Get()
       {
           return this.Ok(this.GetType().FullName);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a concrete controller:

   ```
   [RoutePrefix("foo")]
   public class ConcreteController : ControllerBase
   {
   }
   ```

(Note that the concrete controller has the `[RoutePrefix]`.)

Hope this helps!